# How to compare and sum values of multiple periods using LINQ in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, linq, compare, sum

I have the following example datatable:

```
Value1 Value2 Customer Product Date

100     50   1000     100     1.8.2010

50      20   1000     101     5.1.2010

200     60   1000     100     6.2.2011

180     100  1001     100     7.3.2010

500     700  1000     100     1.1.2010

300     300  1001     100     4.4.2011

250     600  1000     100     3.3.2011
```

And now the user should be able to compare multiple periods. In this example the user chose two periods: 1.1.2010 - 31.12.2010 and 1.1.2011 - 31.12.2011. The result of the example should be:

```
Customer Product SumValue1Period1 SumValue2Period1 SumValue1Period2 SumValue2Period2

1000 100 600 750 450 660

1000 101 50 20 0 0

1001 100 300 100 300 300
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have known number of columns, you can group data by Customer and products and then take conditional sum from grouping and it will make different columns of the resultant query.

Please have a look at following LinqPad program. Sorry, I'm not familiar with VB.Net so I have coded it in C#, but you'll get the fair idea:

```
void Main()
{
    var Period1Start = new DateTime(2010,1,1);
    var Period1End = new DateTime(2010,12,31);
    var Period2Start = new DateTime(2011,1,1);
    var Period2End = new DateTime(2011,12,31);
    List<Item> lst = new List<Item>
    {
      new Item{ Value1 = 100, Value2 = 50, Customer = 1000, Product = 100 , Date = new DateTime(2010,8,1)},
      new Item{ Value1 = 50, Value2 = 20, Customer = 1000, Product = 101 , Date = new DateTime(2010,5,1)},
      new Item{ Value1 = 200, Value2 = 60, Customer = 1000, Product = 100 , Date = new DateTime(2011,2,6)},
      new Item{ Value1 = 180, Value2 = 100, Customer = 1001, Product = 100 , Date = new DateTime(2010,7,3)},    
      new Item{ Value1 = 500, Value2 = 700, Customer = 1000, Product = 100 , Date = new DateTime(2010,1,1)},
      new Item{ Value1 = 300, Value2 = 300, Customer = 1001, Product = 100 , Date = new DateTime(2011,4,4)},
      new Item{ Value1 = 250, Value2 = 600, Customer = 1000, Product = 100 , Date = new DateTime(2011,3,3)} 

    };

    var grp = lst.GroupBy(x=>new{x.Customer, x.Product}).
    Select(y=> new
    {
        Customer = y.Key.Customer,
        Product = y.Key.Product,
        SumValue1Period1 = y.Where(x=>x.Date >= Period1Start && x.Date<= Period1End).Sum(p=>p.Value1),
        SumValue2Period1 = y.Where(x=>x.Date >= Period1Start && x.Date<= Period1End).Sum(p=>p.Value2),
        SumValue1Period2 = y.Where(x=>x.Date >= Period2Start && x.Date<= Period2End).Sum(p=>p.Value1),
        SumValue2Period2 = y.Where(x=>x.Date >= Period2Start && x.Date<= Period2End).Sum(p=>p.Value2)

    });
    Console.WriteLine(grp);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Item
{
    public int Value1{get;set;}
    public int Value2{get;set;}
    public int Customer{get;set;}
    public int Product{get;set;}
    public DateTime Date{get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb737908

Specifically, the '**GroupBy - Nested**' example.  It shows using LINQ to group by 'customer's orders, first by year, and then by month.'  You situation should be more straight forward since it's just the date range.